# Is it possible to use private IP address on GPRS connection

Tags: networking, windows-mobile, gprs

I need to connect my Windows Mobile 5.0 phone to the WAVECOM Q2686 processor acting as a server. The problem is I don't have a public IP address for the server side.

I tried to solve it by using the CSD dial-up connection, where the all you need is phone number of the server and you can use any IP you want. But as of now I couldn't achieve it on my shitty piece of  Windows Mobile phone :/.

As my knowledge of GPRS and GSM is generally slim, I went back to the previous option of using GPRS. Maybe it is possible to use private IP addresses on such connections? But I know too little of GPRS workings to be aware of such possiblity?

Many thanks in advance.

PS. As an additional info - both the phone and the server reside in the same base station area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to have a server running on your windows mobile device and have other device on the internet connect to it? Or do you mean that the server you are running doesn't have a fixed public internet address for your windows mobile device to talk to?

An alternative to using a static ip on the server is to use a dynamic dns service like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) With this service you can run an app on the server that can update the dns records to the current dynamic public ip address and access the server through the dyndns domain name it has been assigned.

As far as your question about using private ip addresses on your gprs connection, the short answer is no. You would need to set up a vpn tunnel to your private network. Some mobile carriers can provide a service where you are allocated a private apn, and they set up a tunnel between themselves and your networks, then your handset would get a private ip address from your allocated pool when it has established the gprs connection, but this isn't a free (or cheap) service and does require hardware at your network end to terminate the tunnels.

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to your provider to get a fixed IP address.

Although you can set it for a dial up connection, doesn't mean it will work. This is totally independent of the system you are using.

With most providers, this is no free service!